# Custom queues not visible on local development server

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a queue.yaml file at the root of my app folder which defines fews custom queues.

If I deploy the app (and the queue.yaml file), it works well and I can submit task to any of the custom queues created. Also I can see all my custom queues (and the default one) [listed here](https://console.developers.google.com//project/_/appengine/taskqueues).
But in my local server development, pushing a task to a custom queue throw an exception`'google\appengine\api\taskqueue\TaskQueueException' with message 'Unknown queue'` and the SDK Console / Task Queues page lists only the default one.

What I'm missing?

BTW I'm on Mac and using the latest version of the GAE launcher (1.9.23.290)

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT

```
queue:
    - name: api
      rate: 10/s

    - name: foo
      rate: 1/m

    - name: bar
```

---

EDIT 2:

It seems to be related to modules since when there are running the queues disappear. If only the default module is running, the custom queues are created and accessible...

I've created a [demo project](https://github.com/jfradj/GAE_QueuesIssue) and [filled an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12396).

Comment: Can you please include your queue.yaml file here ?

Comment: I've edited my post to add it. Since it's working when deployed I'm not sure there might be an error here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the dev server after adding a new queue to your `queue.yaml`?

Comment: Yes I did it many times. I've also try to find if I had to specify this file to the dev server in some manner but it appears that it should be automatic, we should only restart it.

Comment: Is the queue file named exactly `queue.yaml`? Are you using the `appcfg.py update_queues` command or letting it update with `appcfg.py update`?

Comment: The file is perfectly named. For my local tests, I don't do any `appcfg.py` command at all, I  just restart the server. I'm doing the `appcfg.py update_queues` only when deploying the app online.

Comment: Where is your queue.yaml relative to your app.yaml? Are they in the same directory? You should not have to do anything special for your local development server to pick up on the queue changes unless your queue file is in a non-standard location.

Comment: It's at the root of my app directory, just at the same place as the app.yaml

Comment: I'm out of troubleshooting steps then. Given the information, it should work as expected. If you can make a test project that recreates the issue and put it on github or bitbucket it would help.

Comment: While I was making a test project to let you try by your own the issue, I find it... It seems to be related to modules! Indeed, I've modules so I've to edit the launch settings by adding the full path of every modules .yaml file in the extra flag field. Thus each module will be started, but if they are, the custom queues disappear... If I don't specify any extra flag at launch, the modules won't be started (except the default one) but the custom queues will appear!!! I'm making more tests to find what in the modules can raise this issue. kup

Comment: I've created a [test project](https://github.com/jfradj/GAE_QueuesIssue) to demo the bug and submitted an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12396)